# Error when rebuilding a Solr index: unknown field '__display_name_t_cs'

Tags: solr

I am getting this error when trying to rebuild my master index in Solr:

```
Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_master_index_solr|#Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.ConnectStream.InternalWrite(Boolean async, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Net.ConnectStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.CopyTo(Stream input, Stream output)
at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.PostStream(String relativeUrl, String contentType, Stream content, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Post(String relativeUrl, String s)
at SolrNet.Impl.SolrBasicServer`1.SendAndParseHeader(ISolrCommand cmd)
at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrBatchUpdateContext.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 group, Int32 groupSize)
at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrBatchUpdateContext.Commit()
at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex.PerformRebuild(Boolean resetIndex, Boolean optimizeOnComplete, IndexingOptions indexingOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex.Rebuild(Boolean resetIndex, Boolean optimizeOnComplete)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
at (Object , Object[] )
at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)
```

The Solr logs are showing this error:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=sitecore://master/{bfde3d21-3a67-4938-aa90-33da9caf7bf5}?lang=cs-cz&ver=1] unknown field '__display_name_t_cs'
```

Comment: This looks like the schema.xml doesn't have all of the fields defined. the SOLR log error says that a field isn't defined. I would make sure your your schema.xml is correct.

Comment: After you update your schema.xml in solr, ensure you restart the solr instance, to have the effect of inserted dynamicField.

Comment: I was getting same issue while rebuilding master index from Sitecore 9.0.2. For me the fields were already present in the managed schema file. From Sitecore control panel, I clicked "Populate Solr Managed Schema" and populated the schema for index again. Though I verified that populating schema again did not make any changes to managed schema file, rebuilding succeeded without any issues.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sitecore stores language-specific text fields in Solr by adding a suffix that corresponds to the locale name. The field for the `cs-cz` locale is missing in the index schema, so you'll need to add it.

In the schema.xml of every Solr index, insert the following node under `<fields>`:

```xml
<dynamicField name="*_t_cs" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

If you have any other languages defined in Sitecore, check that their corresponding locale-specific fields are also mapped as dynamic fields.

For more information on setting up Solr with Sitecore, check this tutorial:

https://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/search/solr/Configuring-Solr-for-use-with-Sitecore-8/#optional-development-step

Comment: For newer versions of Solr, you will find these fields in the need to edit the `/indexname/conf/managed-schema` file, instead

Answer (score 3):

I have created a new open source Sitecore module called **SmartSolrSchema** to help address this issue and published it [here](https://github.com/dataweaversio/SmartSolrSchema).

It works by patching into Sitecore's populate schema pipeline and reading all language items in your `master` database and then creating appropriate schema entries when using the Sitecore Populate Managed Schema tool.

Answer (score 2):

This is a misconfiguration of the Solr schema.xml like Pete said above and the type and language mapping of Sitecore ContentSearch.

you need check the type matches in 

either for the master index or probably the defaultSolrIndexConfiguration
and the schema for having the extensions for your language (cs-cz mapped to prefix _cs in Solr)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by adding

```
<field fieldName="[XXfield_nameXX]" returnType="string"/>
```

in the `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config` under nodes `[sitecore > contentSearch > indexConfigurations > defaultSolrIndexConfiguration > fieldNames]`

Note: you need to have an entry for each field if you are using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I added a new language-region combination (tn-bw) in LanguageDefinitions.config that was not supported by Sitecore OOB. Due to this change, I started getting similar error while running index rebuilds. I got this solved by following steps -

1. Goto solr\qa\server\solr\configsets\sitecore_configs\conf\schema.xml
2. Look for entries like - `<dynamicField name="*_t_ar" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />`
   and right there at bottom, add an entry for your language as - `<dynamicField name="*_t_tn" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />`
3. Repeat steps 1-2 for schema.xml placed at C:\solr\server\solr\configsets\sitecore_master_suggestor_configs and
   C:\solr\server\solr\configsets\sitecore_web_suggestor_configs as well.

Do not forget to restart your solr server after these config updates. Without restart, the config updates will not reflect.