# No forms are displaying in Sitecore 9 Forms area

Tags: sitecore-forms

Let me start by saying that I have had this happen before and typically I have only had to reindex the Master index. However, nothing is working to display the 15 forms that we have created. I have already been through this post here:

[Why I can't see my forms/templates in the Sitecore Forms application?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8518/why-i-cant-see-my-forms-templates-in-the-sitecore-forms-application)

I can modify the forms through the Content Tree at this point, but I drastically need the UI in order to see where things are placed to make quick changes.

Can anyone help?

If this goes over 24-48 hours, I am going to take to Sitecore Support and log a ticket. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version you use 9.0 or 9.0.1 precisely? Can you update your question with screenshot what you can see when you open Forms? Is browser Dev toolbar showing you some errors during load?

Comment: I am using Version 9. O. There's no real screenshot to show other than it just says no forms to display. If I look at the console in the browser the only thing it is saying that it is not loading is opensans.css. Everything else is fine

Comment: Could you check if you have errors in Solr log. I’ve had the same issue when Solr was not be able to create core for xConnect.

Comment: There is only warning regarding [segments] as seen in the other post. No "ERROR" messages at all.

Comment: I have had this same issue, just haven't had time to troubleshoot it...

Comment: Same boat here just been super busy and haven't had time to really look into it either. But now it's affecting my ability to get bugs fixed quickly. So I'm going to give this a good 24 hours and then send off to support because it definitely needs to be addressed for the community.

Comment: I would raise the ticket immediately and then post back if support get back, you can do both together :)

Comment: Good idea. I'll put in first thing tomorrow morning and then respond back on here what the response is which may be the answer. In the meanwhile if anyone has anything to add please feel free to comment or provide an answer if you have one.

Comment: and if you open this in your browser: `<url to your sitecore site>`/-/item/v1/sitecore/shell?search=&searchConfig={A7C51A03-028A-4414-98DF-116DFAEAE5A6}&sc_content=master&language=en&sorting=d__smallcreateddate&fields=__Created|__Created%20by|__Updated|__Updated%20by|Classification|__Thumbnail&pageIndex=0&pageSize=50 do you see the results?

Comment: That gives me this @chorpo: {"statusCode":500,"error":{"message":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: item"}}. Nonetheless, I have put in a support ticket right now. Awaiting feedback from Sitecore on this one.

Comment: same issue, I tried to hack it by creating it in Experience editor by dropping forms wrapper and tried creating a form, that also gives error.

I thought, If the issue is with my SC9u1 installation, could not explore more cuz caught up in other things.

Comment: @TobyGutierrez - Any news regarding this? Pretty curious...

Comment: Still haven't heard anything from Support after 4 days. Just that they are investigating. When I hear back, I will post all knowledge gained here for all to consume.

Comment: no luck yet. @chorpo  waiting for support  to respond

Comment: Correction, they did get back to me immediately but there is action they need from my part, which I haven't had time to get to. I will be working on that today.

Comment: FYI: I have SC v9.3 installed and this problem still exists. As posted in previous comments, rebuilding the indexes (Control Manager > Indexing Manager > Rebuild) "fixes" it.

Comment: I have answered at this question link: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8518/why-i-cant-see-my-forms-templates-in-the-sitecore-forms-application/32136#32136

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the answer my Sitecore community. Thanks to Sitecore Support!

Wrong Forms folder ID. Somewhere along the check-in source control travels someone must have deleted the original Forms folder, and then created a new Forms folder with a different ID. Because of this one simple change by a developer the Forms Designer was now rendered useless and ineffective.

The solution to this issue is this:

- Do NOT delete the Forms folder and create a new one if you don’t need
  to!
- If you do delete the Forms folder, get it from another instance
  of Sitecore 9.
- If for some reason you want to run with a Forms folder
  with a different ID then you must change to this ID for your new
  Forms folder in the Root field of these items below in the Core
  database: SearchConfig: {60F35FD9-88CB-4DF5-8E78-1E9BF5FE181C}
  AllFormsSearchConfig: {A7C51A03-028A-4414-98DF-116DFAEAE5A6}

My recommendation is to NOT opt for #3 as this will get away from you, and your client down the road unless you document it, keep for future reference, and refer to for future upgrades. Ain’t nobody got time for that! Just opt to get on Slack and ask someone for the OOTB Forms folder item in a package, move all your forms into the correct OOTB Forms folder and you are all set.

https://sitecoresandbox.com/2018/03/09/there-are-no-forms-to-display-in-sitecore-9-forms-designer/

Answer (score 6):

After clean installation of 9.1.1, I have the same issue. I did reindex. I checked IDs.
But I suppose issue is somewhere else. This is from search log:

```
35448 16:58:48 ERROR Solr Error : ["undefined field is_template"] - Query attempted: [(((((_content:(**) OR _name:(**) OR _displayname:(**)) AND (is_template:(1) AND _latestversion:(1))) AND _path:(b701850acb8a4943b2bcdddb1238c103)) AND _templatename:(Form)) AND (-__hidden:(1)  *:*))]
```

Quick solution is to define "is_template" field from "istemplate" field:

```
<field fieldName="istemplate" returnType="bool">Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.IsTemplate,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
<field fieldName="is_template" returnType="bool">Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.IsTemplate,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
```

in default index configuration

Answer (score 4):

I'm adding this answer as well in case you are not in the situation that the marked answer suggests. Another thing to check is your indexes. The forms on the Sitecore Forms page are queried from the search index, not the content tree, and therefore, if your indexes are not populated with those forms, they won't show up. Please refer to this blog post for more information: https://citizensitecore.com/2017/11/19/sitecore-9-forms-form-doesnt-show-up-after-creation/

Rebuilding your master index is the way to resolve that issue (or highlight the forms folder and use the "Reindex Tree" option in the developer toolbar of the content editor).

Comment: Just Reindexing Master and Web worked for me. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue for **sitecore 9.1.0 azure paas**, because in azure search we have field limitation i set up **indexAllFields** to **false**, so need to add "Is Template" filed to index:

```
<include hint="list:AddIncludedField">
   <fieldId>{558F9307-EBAF-480D-88B5-DFE9E63A66DE}</fieldId>
</include>
```

[image]

**Updated 6/20/2019**

Also need to add ishidden field:

```
<fieldId>{39C4902E-9960-4469-AEEF-E878E9C8218F}</fieldId>
```

Comment: "add" = "Check"

Comment: No, not "check". They are referring to the XML configuration, not the Sitecore CE UI.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was an issue with my system templates. Due to some unknown mess-up, none of the /system templates (including the Forms template) had an English version. This threw exceptions when building a query:

```
 at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Utilities.LanguageFallbackDataService.EnsureFallbackVersion(Item rootItem)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Utilities.LanguageFallbackDataService.GetDescendantsByTemplateWithFallback(Item rootItem, TemplateID templateId)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Utilities.LanguageFallbackDataService.GetDescendantsByTemplateWithFallback(Item rootItem, String templateId)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Utilities.QueryBuilder.CreateQuery[T](IProviderSearchContext context, IEnumerable`1 searchStringModel, Item startLocationItem, IEnumerable`1 additionalContexts)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Utilities.QueryBuilder.CreateQuery[T](IProviderSearchContext context, IEnumerable`1 searchStringModel)
   at Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Pipelines.Search.ParseSearchText.Parse(IProviderSearchContext providerSearchContext, String searchText)
   at Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Pipelines.Search.ParseSearchText.Process(SearchArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Pipelines.Request.Search.RunSearchPipeline(RequestArgs args, String searchText, String languageName, Boolean showHiddenItems)
   at Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Pipelines.Request.Search.Process(RequestArgs args)
```

Other than this, I've also noticed that I don't see any forms when I've previously set the database to 'core' in the content editor.

Answer (score 0):

Content language issue can be a problem. unknown field 'heading_t_pl' (poland) is what I got in error logs. It could be any language...

- '*t_cs'
- '*_pl'(poland)
- '*_cz'(czech)

A solution for language addition is given [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2034/error-when-rebuilding-a-solr-index-unknown-field-display-name-t-cs/2042).

As @bushland25 pointed out, The forms on the Sitecore Forms page are queried from the search index, not the content tree.

So in my case, I went specifically to that content item(form) and did "Reindex Tree" option in the developer toolbar of the content editor. UK contents worked, but other countries gave error on the content editor(when I did re-indextree).

Answer (score 0):

**For anyone who is coming from Upgrade route**

I upgraded Sitecore 8.2 to 9.2 via sitecore upgrade but couldn't use form fields - note that in my case I was able to see the form items both in Forms & Content editor but couldn't edit/save them(`400-Bad request` error while adding form fields). Following steps fixed it:

1. While upgrading the `_Standard Value` of Form template items aren't created properly and essentially the Forms pipeline needs the Standard Values. Got the templates from a fresh sitecore instance to fix it. The location in content tree is `sitecore/templates/System/Forms`
2. If you have custom processors interfering `HttpRequest` pipeline `e.g. Custom MarkupProcessor`, check them out if they are stopping the Form field rendering

Answer (score 0):

One thing the previous answers elude to but never explicitly call out is: If you've just set up a new Sitecore instance (a local dev instance for example) make sure to build your indexes via:

`Dashboard -> Control Panel -> Indexing manager -> Rebuild`

Answer (score -1):

Go to the Control panel and below there will be INDEXING, Click the Indexing manager and Rebuild all the indexes

Comment: Welcome to SSE community Shareef. I am down voting your answer as the answer above from @bushland25 already talks about index rebuilding in detail. Please update your answer if you want to suggest another approach to resolve the issue. Or once you have sufficient reputation, you will be able to post it as a comment.

Comment: just to correct it - Do Index rebuild but only for master and core issue will be resolved.

@AmitabhVyas I can see there is no above comment/answer who mentioned to rebuild master+core index if no forms are appearing on the form dashboard.

Please correct me if i missed something.